# If the derivatives of two bounded variation functions are equal in $L_1$ then $F=G$ almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $F$ and $G$ are functions of bounded variation on a closed interval $I$. Then we know that both functions are differentiable almost everywhere.Does it follow that If the derivative of $F$ and the derivative of $G$ belong in the same equivalence class in $L_1$ then $F=G$ almost everywhere?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about $\chi_{[0,1/2]}(x)$ and the function that is identically 0 on $I=[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes that's a simple counterexample

Comment: You want something stronger, like absolute continuity for this to hold.

Comment: I see that makes sense thanks for your comment

Comment: sure thing, happy studying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. @qbert already gave an counterexample. One might think that it is possible to fix this pathology by assuming additionally that both functions are continuous, but, in fact, that's not good enough.

Consider on $[0,1]$ the Cantor function $F$, which is continuous and increasing (hence of bounded variation) and whose derivative equals zero Lebesgue almost everywhere. If we set $G=0$ (which is also continuous and of bounded variation), then $F'=G'$ almost everywhere but $F(x) \neq G(x)$ for all $x >0$.

In fact, it is even possible to construct a continuous **strictly** increasing function $F$ such that $F'=0$ Lebesgue almost everywhere. This illustrates that knowing the a.e. derivative of a function doesn't really say anything about its behaviour (e.g. monotonicity).